# Cannot inject EJB specified in applicationcontext.xml in jboss 7

Tags: java, spring, jboss, dependency-injection, java-ee-6

I'm trying to migrate my Java EE application from jboss 5.1 to jboss 7.1 and getting a deployment error.

My EAR has 2 EJB modules and 1 WAR module. both EJB modules gets deployed without any issue. but when i'm trying to deploy with the WAR module it says

`Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name "className" Injection of resource fields failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'java:global/ear/ejb/FacadeBean!com.ejb.business.SearchFacade' is defined: not found in JNDI environment`

because of copyright issues i'm unable to disclose the full class names. but "classname" is defined as a bean in my spring application context file and it has a dependency injection of SearchFacade which again has some dependencies.

whats confusing is that in the jboss log it shows that SearchFacade is deployed without any issues.

i'm finding so hard to find a solution for this issue. any help will be greatly appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like spring is not able to determine that the EJB component is in that EJB Jar and you need to enforce that the components in that EJB jar are initialized and started before the components in you WAR.

Did you tried to set  element into your application*xml and see if that helped?

Something like this in your application.xml

```
<application-name>EAR</application-name>
<initialize-in-order>true</initialize-in-order>
<module><ejb>EJB.jar</ejb></module>
<module><web><web-uri>WAR.war</web-uri><context-root>....
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply.  i added an application.xml to the project and added the content as u suggested. But still getting the same error.

Comment: Hi my bad i had done something wrong when specifying the modules. i corrected it and now everything seems fine. thanks a lot for helping me out.